# Apollo Query Component is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm having some issues where the following functional component using the `Query` Apollo component is throwing errors when it's added to my App.js. I can't figure out what exactly is going on- the error I'm getting is

`Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

That,  as far as I can tell from my research, represents EITHER an import error or an error in which the function being returned by my App is undefined. It's not an import error, as I've double and triple checked that it's both being exported and imported by default.

For context, I'm trying to conditionally render a certain react component based on whether or not a value exists in my database. I have that value in my application schema and my GraphQL query seems to be returning the proper document node.

Code below:
My Query to conditionally select which form is rendered:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import BillingForm from '../ConfigureBilling/BillingForm'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import Query from 'react-apollo'


import UpdateBilling from '../ConfigureBilling/UpdateBilling'


const STRIPE_QUERY = gql`
  query Workspace {
    workspaces(workspaceUuid: "test_workspace_id", withUsers: false) {
      stripeCustomerId
    }
  }
`
console.log(STRIPE_QUERY)

const BillingConfig = ({ workspace }) => {
  return (
    <Query query={STRIPE_QUERY}>
      {({ data }) => {
        const { workspaces } = data
        return workspaces.stripeCustomerId != null ? (
          <BillingForm workspace={workspace} />
        ) : (
          <UpdateBilling workspace={workspace} />
        )
      }}
    </Query>
  )
}

BillingConfig.propTypes = {
  workspace: PropTypes.object,
}

export default BillingConfig
```

My index.js file that renders the actual component in my application:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import GetWorkspace from '../GetWorkspace'
import Module from '../../app/Module'
import BillingForm from '../ConfigureBilling/BillingForm'
import BillingConfig from '../Data/BillingConfig'

import { Elements, StripeProvider } from 'react-stripe-elements';
import UpdateBilling from '../ConfigureBilling/UpdateBilling'

class Billing extends React.Component {
  menu = {
    nav: 'workspace',
  }

  render() {
    const { workspace } = this.props

    // Error handled
    if (!workspace) return <Module nada />

    return (
      <Module metaTitle={'Billing | ' + workspace.label} menu={this.menu}>
        <StripeProvider apiKey="TESTKEY">
          <Elements>
            <BillingForm workspace={workspace} />
          </Elements>
        </StripeProvider>
      </Module>
    )
  }
}

Billing.propTypes = {
  workspace: PropTypes.object,
}

export default GetWorkspace(Billing)
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be throwing that error?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Possibly related to unions and __resolveType https://spectrum.chat/apollo/react-apollo/can-query-ever-return-data-undefined~0a8940f0-d294-49be-8ad4-a7e3105a05cc